# Type mismatch (Error 13) when using Sumifs

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to add the value of all the cells in column Q that has a date between Now and thirty minutes ago in column Z AND has a certain name in column Y.

```
dim nu as Date
dim ThirtyMinAgo as Date
dim currentBestTopThree as Integer

nu = WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(Now * 48, 0) / 48
ThirtyMinAgo = nu - 1 / 48

currentBestTopThree = _
    Application.SumIfs(Sheets("topthreecheck").Range("Y2:Y" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, employeelist(i), _
     Sheets("topthreecheck").Range("Z2:Z" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, "<" & nu, _
     Sheets("topthreecheck").Range("Z2:Z" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, ">=" & ThirtyMinAgo, _
     Sheets("topthreecheck").Range("Q2:Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
```

`employeelist(i)` is an array that contains all the unique names in column Y.

`i` is the current iteration of an `For` loop that loops between `1 and Ubound(employeelist)`

Column Z contains dates formatted as "2020-03-01 08:32:23"

Column Y contains names

Column Q contains numbers

The SumIfs line gives me the error

> Type Mismatch(Error 13)

I tried to hard code a date:

```
currentBestTopThree = Application.SumIfs(Sheets("topthreecheck").Range("Z2:Z" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, #2/25/2020 9:30:00 AM#, _
Sheets("topthreecheck").Range("Q2:Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
```

But it still shows the error.

I also tried:

```
If Sheets("topthreecheck").Range("Z2") = #2/25/2020 9:30:00 AM# Then
End If
```

And that line doesn't give me the Type Mismatch error.

Anyone knows what's going on here?

It's as if the code tries to sum the dates. I guess that's why it gives the error. Since `currentBestTopThree` is an integer. But I've tried both

`SumIfs(Sum_range, Range1, Criteria1)` and

`SumIfs(Range1, Criteria1, Sum_range)`

One of them should be the right one!

Comment: Where are you defining `employeelist(i)` or `i` for that matter?

Comment: It's defined in at the start of the code. The list is created there. And it contains all the names of the employees in column Y. The code above is part of a `For` loop that loops from `1 to UBound(employeelist)` That's where the `i` comes from.

Comment: And how many rows contain actual data? All `1048576`? Because that's what `Rows.Count` will give you. Did you mean to give it a calculated `lastRow` instead?

Comment: It's about 200 rows. I guess using Last row will speed it up. (Eventhough it's quite fast fast) I'll check it out.

Comment: There, changed it. I googled and this was the method I found!

Comment: I still get Type Mismatch though.

Comment: The short answer is that you have to dimension currentBestTopThree as variant, not integer (so it can handle errors). I think you've got an extra criterion in as well.